# CSS3 Frontend Framework without javascript

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks, frontend

is there a simple css3 front-end framework that works perfectly fine without the use of javascript or JQuery !!
Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look at [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/)

Comment: please thumbs up if it solved your question